# Is there a transformation whose differential is the following

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, transformation

Let $T$ be a transformation

is $$dT = \begin{bmatrix} y & x \\ xy & x+y\end{bmatrix}$$

Any hints?

Comment: If this is the Jacobian, what do you know about the mixed partials from the second row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

If you are searching a function 
$$
T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \qquad T(x,y)=(T_1(x,y),T_2(x,y))
$$
such that
$$
dT = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial T_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial T_1}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial T_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial T_2}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} y & x \\ xy & x+y\end{bmatrix}
$$

than note that from the second row, we have:
$$
T_2(x)=\int xy dx =\frac{1}{2}x^2y+C(y)
$$
but 
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial y} \left(\frac{1}{2}x^2y+C(y) \right)
$$
cannot be $x+y$